# Can i get an image output for a Developer Express WebChartControl?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, webchartcontrol

I have a WebChartControl on my web page. When the chart was generated, an image is being produced and it was shown on the page.

Is there a way to get and save this chart as an image output on runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Ultimately the image comes from a URL of some sort.  Do a view-source on the web page and see what that URL looks like.  With a certain amount of reverse-engineering, usage of System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter, perhaps an HttpHandler, etc. you should be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for exporting an image from a Developer Express chart control (web) is:

```
((IChartContainer)[Your web chart control]).Chart.ExportToImage([Your file name], ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ExportToImage method of the ChartControl object .. This is WinForm code, but the same concept should hold true for WebChartControl:

```
    Dim chart As ChartControl = ChartControl1.Clone()
    chart.Size = New Size(800, 600)
    chart.ExportToImage("file.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```